# Angular/Typescript: Accessing object data in constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Trying to access an object's data in a constructor returns an "undefined" object. It works on the ngOnInit() function, but the data (going to get reset) is needed **every time** the component starts.

```
   import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
   @Input() data: any;


   constructor(dataService: DataService)
   {
     console.log(this.data); // undefined
   }


   ngOnInit()
   {
     console.log(this.data) // works here
   }
```

Comment: Where does data come from ? How is it defined ?

Comment: Is the `data` property defined in the object/class?

Comment: Data is an input, @Input() data: any;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read this [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)?

It said:

> After creating a component/directive by calling its constructor,
>   Angular calls the lifecycle hook methods in the following sequence at
>   specific moments

And then it lists all methods according to the order of excecution.

You can read the full documentation of **[lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)**, it is good to know this when we start developing application using Angular.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the value of a component input inside its constructor, except for the initial value you assign to it.

Why?

Well, easy: Angular must create the component first (by invoking its constructor). Only then can it set the inputs. If you try to use an input property in the constructor, obviously it will be `undefined`.

In your case, you should use the value in `ngOnInit`, or, if you really need it in the constructor, retrieve it in another way (by using an injected service, a global shared object ...).